# get data from firebase and put it in a String

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get information from firebase and stock it in a String.

How can i do that in Java?

I want to get:

**48.8287302** 
*and*
**2.3649081**

From

[image]

Comment: Hi Sasi. What have you tried so far? Are you using a particular Java library to consume services from Firebase? You need to show us your attempt by sharing some code snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Firebase documentation? It's pretty clear [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

There are a few things you need to do first:

1. [Ensure your project is set up in the Firebase dashboard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start).
2. You need to incorporate Firebase into your project, using something like Gradle.

Now for actual code, you need to get a reference to where your data is stored in your database reference. Once you have that, you have to provide the path to your strings in your database. Here's an example

```
private void getData(){
    DatabaseReference db = mDatabase.getChild("customer-requests").getChild("M7-J...").getChild("I");
    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                strs.add(snapshot.getValue());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Make sure you change the `getChild()` calls above to the actual names.

Answer (score 0):

**Call this method to read the values that you want, I assumed that the values are `double`**

```
private void readValues(){


//the reference
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("customer_requests");

//listener
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

//I assume the values are doubles in the database (if floats use Float.class)

//get the values
double value0_float = ds.child("I").child("0").getValue(Double.class);
double value1_float = ds.child("I").child("1").getValue(Double.class);

//convert to strings
String value0 = String.valueOf(value0_float);
String value1 = String.valueOf(value1_float);




}

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
};

//attach the listener
ref.addValueEventListener(listener);




}
```